# Why can a 5x4 matrix never be surjective?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

My thought is that since a matrix can only be surjective if null(T)= n-m, no matrix can have a nullity of -1 therefore a 5x4 matrix cannot be surjective. Is this a valid proof?

Comment: Recall that rank(T)= dim( Im(T)).

Answer (score 1):

A $5×4$ matrix represents a linear transformation  $T$ from a $4$ dimensional vector space to a $5$ dimensional vector space. If $T$ is surjective, then the rank of  $T=5$. But rank nullity theorem implies that $\operatorname{rank}(T)+\operatorname{nullity}(T)=4$, i.e. 
$\operatorname{nullity}(T)=-1,$a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

Recall that a basis for $\mathbb{R^5}$ requires exactly $5$ linearly independent vectors.

What is the maximum rank for $A\in M_{5\times 4}$?

Comment: I'm supposed to justify it using the rank nullity theorem

Comment: @ElliotSilver Yes that's a direct consequance, I've added an additional tip for that.

Comment: The max rank would be 5?

Comment: @ElliotSilver Recall that for a $n\times m$ matrix $rank(A) \le \min (m,n)$. That's an important concept you should clarify. Refer to [Rank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rank_(linear_algebra)).

Comment: Thank you for trying to help, but I don't think I understand what you mean, the rank is 5 which is less or equal to 5?

Comment: @ElliotSilver What is the rank of a $10\times 1$ matrix?

Comment: @ElliotSilver Opsss.sorry for the typo now fixed..of course $rank(A) \le \min (m,n)$ :)